# How to add an interval for auto scroll in kendo scroll view?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I want to add a functionality such that the carousel keeps changing for a short interval of time. I was unable to find a solution for this which uses only jQuery.

Code checked out on Kendo website:  https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scrollview/events

I checked out and found the automaticViewChangeInterval for vue js and angular but found nothing on jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scrollview/events">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/themes/7.0.1/default/default-main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.3.1010/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    
    

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../content/shared/styles/examples-offline.css">
    <script src="../content/shared/js/console.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example" style="margin:auto; width:70%">
    <div id="scrollView" style="width: 660px; height: 420px; max-width: 100%; margin: auto;">
        <div class="photo photo1" data-role="page">
        </div><div class="photo photo2" data-role="page">
        </div><div class="photo photo3" data-role="page">
        </div><div class="photo photo4" data-role="page">
        </div><div class="photo photo5" data-role="page">
        </div><div class="photo photo6" data-role="page">
        </div><div class="photo photo7" data-role="page">
        </div><div class="photo photo8" data-role="page">
        </div><div class="photo photo9" data-role="page">
        </div><div class="photo photo10" data-role="page">
        </div>
    </div>   
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {


            function onChange(e) {
                kendoConsole.log("page " + e.nextPage);
            }

            function onRefresh(e) {
                kendoConsole.log("Total: " + e.pageCount + " Current: " + e.page);
            }

            $("#scrollView").kendoScrollView({
                enablePager: true,
                contentHeight: "100%",
                change: onChange,
                refresh: onRefresh
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>

<style>


    #scrollview-home .photo {
        display: inline-block;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
    }

    .photo1 {
        background-image: url("../content/shared/images/photos/11.jpg");
    }

    .photo2 {
        background-image: url("../content/shared/images/photos/12.jpg");
    }
    
</style>

        <div class="kd-example-console">
            <div class="header">
                <span class="title">CONSOLE LOG</span>
                <span class="clear kd-text-secondary">Clear log</span>
            </div>
            <div class="console"></div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such configuration in the API indeed. But you could use the [next](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scrollview/methods/next) and/or [scrollTo](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scrollview/methods/scrollto) methods to achieve similar result. Here is a [modified example](https://dojo.telerik.com/OZuTIDAy).

Answer (score 0):

The example is great! Thank you!!!

Now, if we add another 5-second pause after clicking on the radio button of the page, we can recommend TELERIK for use.

Comment: Well, you can modify the example to achieve that - check if the event target is the scrollview navigation and if so update the delay. Here is an update - https://dojo.telerik.com/iHibOzat

Comment: Aleksandar, hi! Works great!!!! I tested all modes and situations, I will use it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik provided its own version - https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-add-an-interval-for-auto-scroll-in-kendo-scrollview. It works too.